# How to get audio files URIs having directory URI?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

User choose directory and I need get all audio files URIs in that directory.
I have directory URI something like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads
```

When I try use ContentResolver method query I get an error:

```
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9999, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads flg=0xc3 }} to activity {com.example.directorypicker/com.example.directorypicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads
```

How to make URI supported?
Maybe you have alternative options?

Comment: @pskink yeah, but i created my intent with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and my path always has `/tree/someDir`. when i cut /downloads i got ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT requirement

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`'s docs say: *"To gain access to descendant (child, grandchild, etc) documents, use buildDocumentUriUsingTree(Uri, String) and buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(Uri, String) with the returned URI."* - did you try those?

Comment: @pskink if i understand correctly, the files in this folder are indexed (the index is the second parameter). but i don't know how get these strings. trying (https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.provider.DocumentsContract&method=buildDocumentUriUsingTree) and `DocumentsContract.getDocumentId` is crashed with `Invalid URI: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads`. i thought param self in that example is like my directory URI, but something goes wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the `Uri` that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and pass it to `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`. That will give you a [`DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) object, and you can call `listFiles()` to traverse the document tree to find your audio content.